# Removing word highlights in vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting

When I write code in vscode jupyter notebook I get random parts of my code highlighted and I would like to turn that off:

[image]

How can I turn that off? I tried playing around in vscode setting highlight section, but only one of those is in the notebook category which is to draw a line around the cell that is being executed.